# How to best ask users to provide input when changing between some statuses but not others of a project?

Tags: input, status

I am working on a platform in which the user can, among other things, manage the status of projects. At the moment, the user select the new status by clicking a button, and the change is immediately effective. This is done on the project page (accessed through a table listing all the projects). There is a panel on top of the page containing a tag with the current status and one or multiple button labeled with the possible next statuses. The flow between status is linear, meaning that the user is always moving on a next status and cannot go back,  but at certain stages of the process, certain statuses can be skipped. Therefore, sometimes there is only one button (user can move from status 1 to status 2) or multiples (from status 2, user can move to status 3, 4 or 5).

Visually it looks something like this:
[image]

Now, as part of a new process, it will be required that the user provides a certain numeric value when changing from certain status to others, like from status 3 to 4, and 4 to 5. Depending on the project, it might be one single value or multiple values. This values should then also be visible and possibly editable.

I am unsure on how to create a good user experience for asking the value in such context. My currents thoughts are:

- displaying one or multiple fields upfront seems a bad ideas since it might not be clear for which status they apply, as there might be multiple selectable statuses that require this value at the same time in the panel. Or they might just be irrelevant noise if the user is changing between statuses that do not require this value.
- asking for the value input in a modal once the user click the new status - it is rather disruptive of the user flow, especially since they are now used to just click the button in order to change the status. Also in a modal I am not sure how to make clear that the value is required to change the status, and that the status would be not change if they close the modal without saving the value - sounds especially bad since they already clicked on the button that they are used to have an immediate effect on the status.

I would really happy to hear your thoughts or ideas, as I am kind of stuck on how to move forward. Once I have some ideas that feels worth testing, I am usually able to test them with users, but with this one I am not really sure what would be even a good starting point.